# How to load a signed assembly dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, .net

```
Assembly myDll = Assembly.LoadFrom("D:\\ClassLib.dll, Version=1.0.0.0, 
                                   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=173d654960d26d29");
```

I am getting the exception saying "Could not load the assembly"
Please help me here.

Comment: try like : ``Assembly.LoadFrom("D:\\ClassLib.dll")``

Comment: A signed assembly or an Unsigned assembly doesn't make any difference in that case. I want to load the assembly with fully qualified path(with pulickeytoken) so that I make sure it is not tampered.

Comment: @Yaswanth please refer this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/837908) and see `Method 2: Use an application configuration (.config) file with the <codeBase> tags`

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation for loading assembly. Try giving just the assembly path as an argument to this method and it would work as per the example in documentation. 
In order to check the authenticity of your assembly what you can do is following:

```
    string filePath = "C:/path/to/file.dll";
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(filePath);
    Module module = assembly.GetModules().First();
    X509Certificate certificate = module.GetSignerCertificate();
    if (certificate == null)
    {
         // file is not signed.
    }
```

As a matter of fact once your assembly is loaded you have most of the properties such as version number etc. in the assembly object.

Comment: Specifying only Assembly name wont ensure us that I am loading the correct assembly right? If some one has tampered it or some other assembly with same name but no signing, even in that case I load without any problem, which should not be the case. If we load along with PublicKeyToken then we can ensure we are loading the correct library. Please correct me If I'm wrong

Comment: Once I load the assembly I can check for the public Key and version number details. Finally I had to compromise with this .                                   string pathToDll = "D:\\ClassLib.dll";
                Assembly myDll = Assembly.LoadFrom("D:\\ClassLib.dll");
                if (myDll.FullName == "ClassLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=173d654960d26d29")
                {
                           //do your job
                }
                else
                    throw new FileNotFoundException();  Anyhow thanks guys for your time and help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2004/06/07/checking-for-a-valid-strong-name-signature/) on MSDN website, there is a better way to check validity.

1. Paste this 2 line of code to the top of your relevant class.

```
[DllImport("mscoree.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern bool StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx(string wszFilePath, bool fForceVerification, ref bool pfWasVerified);
```

2. Load your assembly

```
var filePath = "C:/whatever.dll";
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(filePath);
```

3. Set the last 2 parameters regarding to your needs and call the function.
   [Little helper table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vldI.png)

```
var alertMessage = "Spoofed!";
var isValid = StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx(filePath, ....);
if (!isValid)
    throw new FileNotFoundException(alertMessage, filePath);
```

Note: As far as I know there is no managed version of this. So, be thread-safe when you use this function!

Answer (score 0):

you can load the Assembly as follows

```
string path = @"D:\ClassLib.dll";
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
```

More Sources [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/837908)

Comment: A signed assembly or an Unsigned assembly doesn't make any difference in that case. I want to load the assembly with fully qualified path(with pulickeytoken) so that I make sure it is not tampered.